# How to submit an array of integers in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, postgresql, parameters

I would like to know if there is a way to have some sort of input field in a Rails form, so that if the user enters `1, 2, 3`, then `params[:model][:attribute]` returns `[1, 2, 3]` or at least `['1', '2', '3']`, but not `['1, 2, 3']`.

Background:

I have a model `Foo`, which has an attribute `bar_ids`. The datatype of this attribute in the PostgresQL database is [Array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html). I've tried several things:

- if `f.text_field :bar_ids` then `params[:foo][:bar_ids]` returns `'1, 2, 3'`
- if `f.text_field_tag 'foo[bar_ids][]'` then `params[:foo][:bar_ids]` returns `['1, 2, 3']`
- if `f.number_field :bar_ids` then `params[:foo][:bar_ids]` returns `'1'` if I input only `1` and the form does not allow to input multiple numbers

So, again my question - is there a way to construct my form in such a way, so that Rails automatically parses the input to the respective datatype, in my case - an array of integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People usually edit the `params` manually before updating the model:

```
 params[:model][:attribute] = params[:model:][:attribute].split(',')
 # ...
 Model.update_attributes(params[:model])
```

It is usually done in controller action or in `before_action`.